# How do I abstract and secure the same connection string from many applications centrally?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, connection-string, windows-server

I have several web applications running on the same server. All of them have the internal IP address of the database server hardcoded into their `Web.config` files as well as the username and password for the database. I am in the midst of performing many server upgrades and will have to go through all of those applications and update the connection strings everywhere. I would like to have a centralized and secure place to store the connection string.

Is there a daemon or application I can place on the server that can securely contain the connection string details for the database, provide a 'virtual' connection string for my applications to point at, and tunnel the requests back and forth?

The legacy applications are running LINQ-to-SQL and some of them have been updated to use a bit of Entity Framework.

Comment: That sounds like a complicated way to do it. Can't you batch edit the connection strings out of the web.config and put them in machine.config instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

1. PowerShell to update the web.config files (some sample code to get you started below)
2. Web.deploy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

$dbServer = ReadHostIfNull $dbServer "Enter name of database server"
    $dbName = ReadHostIfNull $dbNameSAM "Enter name of SAM database"
    $dbUserName = ReadHostIfNull $dbUserName "Enter SQL authentication username for database (leave blank for integrated security)"

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=$dbServer;Initial Catalog=$dbName;$securityPart"

Write-Output "Modifying web.config..."
if($webConfigPath -eq "")
{
    $configFile = Get-WebConfigFile "IIS:/Sites/$webSite/$vDirSAM"
    $webConfigPath = $configFile.FullName
}

$configXml = [xml](Get-Content $webConfigPath)

UpdateAppSetting $configXml "ConnectionString" $connectionString

function UpdateAppSetting
{ param ($configXml, $key, $newValue)
    $configXml.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/appSettings/add[@key = ""$key""]").value = "$newValue"
}
```